Set CLASSPATH in AWS Lambda
Is there any way to set CLASSPATH in Lambda?
I would like to managed my properties file centrally at an EFS folder shared with Lambda.
For example in tomcat I can set it in setenv.sh file
CLASSPATH="/home/AP/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/AP/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/home/AP/app/apenv"
And in my code, i just do something like this
        ResourceBundle bundle = null;
        try {
            bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle('foo');
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
        }

